# Postfix increment operator in JAVA

Tags: java, postfix-operator

I'm studying about postfix increment operator in JAVA, and curious about why the result is `6` when coding like this.

```java
int b = 3;
b += b++;
        
System.out.println(b);
```

I think that due to the `+=` operator, `3` is added to `b`, making it `6`,
and then due to the `++` operator, `1` is added to `6`, resulting in `b` being `7`.
But the compile result showed me `6`.

Can someone explain why my understanding is incorrect?

Comment: This equates to `b = b + b++`, where both `b`s on the RHS have the value 3; the postincrement then happens, then the assignment of 6 to `b`, so the effect of the postincrement is lost. Operator precedence at work here.

Comment: Java Language Specification [15.7.2. Evaluate Operands before Operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se22/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.2): "The Java programming language guarantees that every operand of an operator (except the conditional operators &&, ||, and ? :) appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the operation itself is performed." And `++` is evaluated before `+=`. (operator *precedence*)

Comment: @user85421 it is not operator precedence but evaluation order that is important. The chapter of the Java Language specification even has this in the title: "**Evaluate** Operands before Operation".

Comment: @Thomas that *chapter* is not about the order of operations, just of operands of **one** specific operation - in a *strange* language, the combined assignment could have higher *precedence* then the increment, that is, add/assign `b` to `b` and then increment `b`; kind of `( b (+= b) )++` (looks absurd since we are not used to it, and also because of some syntactic problems)

Comment: @Thomas in other words, *operator precedence* also plays a role in this question, actually it is, IMHO, as important as the evaluation order of operands! They go hand-in-hand. And that **chapter** also has a section [15.7.3. Evaluation Respects Parentheses and Precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se22/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.2)

Comment: @user85421 operator precedence and evaluation order are orthogonal aspects: operator precedence dictates how an expression is parsed (in other words: the "meaning" of an expression), the evaluation order dictates in which sequence the subexpressions are evaluated.

Comment: @Thomas I know, and you cannot say that operator precedence is **not important** in this question; or do you not agree that, if the (compound-) assignment had higher precedence than postfix increment, the result would be as expected by OP? (as I already tried to show in previous comment) And how "an expression is parsed" also dictates the order in which it is evaluated

Comment: @user85421 operator precedence is involved, because if the compound assignment had higher precedence than postfix increment then the compiler would need to parse it as `(b += b)++;` and would complain since `(b += b)` is a value but the post increment needs a variable. However how an expression is parsed does **not** dictate the evaluation order - the simplest example being `a + b * c` with is parsed as `a + (b * c)` but still `a` is evaluated first, `b` second and `c` last.

Answer (score 1):

We declare the variable `b` and initialize it to `3`.

Then we have this line, `b += b++`;

Let's dissect it.

You are correct that `b++` deals with the postfix increment operator.  However, note that `b` gets incremented after we take the value of `b` (this is the case in which we are dealing with the postfix increment operator!).

So, the right hand side is really `3` because the value of `b` is `3` and we increment `b` after ("post") getting this value.

So, the whole expression is really just `b += 3`.

We are incrementing the value of `b` by `3`, so `b = 6`.

Then, remembering that since we have the postfix increment operator, we will then have to increase `b` by `1`, only on the right hand side (not on the whole expression).

However, we will not again do `b += 1` on the whole expression, so `b = 6` at the end of this program.

*If you want to continue writing this program such that we will increment b again, please feel free to do so. Since the prefix increment operator can be contrasted with the postfix increment operator, why don't you try a sample program with that (if you haven't already) and understand it?*

If anything I said confused you, please comment on this!